# How to check if a date period is embraced by another date period in python?

Tags: python, date

What is the most pythonic way to check if a date period is embraced by another date period in python?

for example

```
start_1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 16, 20, 30)
end_1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 20, 30)

start_2 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 20, 30)
end_2 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 22, 30)
```

so `[start_1, end_1]` obviously lies inside `[start_2, end_2]`, you can check it by using `<`, `>` operators, but I'd like to know if there's a library function to perform this check easily.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using a pip module:

```
pip install DateTimeRange
```

which can be used:

```
>>> start_1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 16, 20, 30)
>>> end_1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 20, 30)
>>> start_2 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 20, 30)
>>> end_2 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 22, 30)
>>> dtr1 = datetimerange.DateTimeRange(start_1, end_1)
>>> dtr2 = datetimerange.DateTimeRange(start_2, end_2)
```

You can check whether one range intersects the other:

```
>>> dtr1.is_intersection(dtr2)
True
```

But it does not show whether the range is fully within the other. To check whether a time range contains another, you still have to check boundaries:

```
>>> dtr1.start_datetime in dtr2
True
>>> dtr1.end_datetime in dtr2
True
```

Though I believe this is a good opportunity for a patch, to implement the `__contains__` method in a fashion that supports for `datetimerange` as LHS argument of the `in` operator.

```
>>> dtr1 in dtr2
[…] /datetimerange/__init__.py", line 136, in __contains__
return self.start_datetime <= value <= self.end_datetime
TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.datetime() <= DateTimeRange()
```

*Nota Bene*: I have [pushed a commit](https://github.com/thombashi/DateTimeRange/pull/12) to make that possible, so now the following works:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import datetimerange
>>> start_1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 16, 20, 30)
>>> start_2 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 20, 30)
>>> end_1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 20, 30)
>>> end_2 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 22, 30)
>>> dtr1 = datetimerange.DateTimeRange(start_1, end_1)
>>> dtr2 = datetimerange.DateTimeRange(start_2, end_2)
>>> 
>>> dtr1 in dtr2
True
>>> dtr2 in dtr1
False
```

HTH

Comment: my patch has just been merged, so now with [`datetimerange` v0.2.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DateTimeRange/0.2.1) you *can* do `dtr1 in dtr2` ☺

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the date time. `end2-end1` and `end2-start1` should be a positive delta. Similary `start2-start1` should be negative. If this condition is satisfied then first time lies within second.
For input in your question:

```
>>> start_1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 16, 20, 30)
>>> end_1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 20, 30)
>>>
>>> start_2 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 20, 30)
>>> end_2 = datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 17, 22, 30)

>>> (end_2 - start_1).total_seconds()
93600.0
>>> (end_2 - start_1).total_seconds()
93600.0
>>> (start_2 - start_1).total_seconds()
-172800
```

If result of first and second is positive while third is negative then first time is within second. This assuming that your end time is greater than start time for both cases. It is almost same no of instructions.